# Why does Play report java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for a class on Windows (while it works fine on Linux)?

Tags: windows, scala, playframework, sbt, slick

I have a Play Framework project. Till now, I have been working on it only on linux, and everything was fine. Now I am trying to run it on windows. However without luck.
I get all the time the exception:

```
[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: models/Users (wrong name: models/users)]
```

(`model.Users` is my model case class, `model.Users` is my table, `model.users` is my companion object which contains operations on table such as `save`, `find`, etc.).

I've tried to change project location, clean, compile and other things... Nothing works.

I am using:

- sbt.version=0.13.5
- playframework=2.3.4
- slick=2.1.0
- java version "1.7.0_67"

Any idea?

Comment: Even I'm facing the same problem when moving projects from Linux to Windows. Full of errors. Did you try to rebuild the project like 'activator eclipse ', or 'activator idea' based on the ide you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a case sensitivity issue. You seem to have one class `model.users` and one class `model.Users`. Linux filesystems are usually case-sensitive, windows filesystems are not. Try renaming your classes so their names are unique regardless of case.

Comment: So stupid, so simple, a lot of time wasted... grr... windows :) Thank you. It's a shame that I had to rename my classes to make it work on windows...